# ADF Self Hosted Runtime consuming all of the memory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are running ADF pipelines in V1 and have self hosted integration runtime. The integration runtime is consuming almost all the memory and not releasing it. The machine is getting failed in such cases. 
Is there a way to control memory uses for integration runtime?

Answer (score 0):

There's continous effort to improve the memory usage of self-hosted integration runtime. Could you please try the latest version which was released on June 6th.